With both 14.0 and 14.1 Save as PDF (print preview) has become completely mangled
For over a decade, I have been using the same method of creating and saving notebooks as PDF.  For some reason saving to PDF started to produce complete gibberish for most of the styles I use.  It happens with all other stylesheets I have tried.
For example, this is what the notebook looks like:

This is what the PDF output looks like:

The same notebook prints fine under Windows 11.
I have tried --cleanstart and running from a different user account. I've tried both versions 14.0 and 14.1.  I have rebooted.  I've tried with a different windows manager. The result is the same each time.
Apparently the problem started in the middle of outputting one of my notebooks since the first part looks normal, but the rest is mangled.
This is the platform information:

My notebooks use a derivative of the Textbook.nb stylesheet. The character mangling doesn't seem to happen with the default stylesheet, but that is not compatible with my several dozen notebooks.
Any ideas?

I just tried saving a notebook as PDF with Mathematica 14.1 on Fedora 40 (GNOME, kernel 6.10, Nvidia RTX with proprietary drivers). The PDF document appears normal.

Did you have a non-default style sheet?  I have ugly but legible output with the default style sheet.  The Textbook.nb style sheet is one that is giving me problems.

Hmm...you're correct. I have a normal output for the default stylesheet, but gibberish for the Testbook stylesheet.

I opened the PDFs from Linux and Windows with Emacs and did C-c C-c to see the raw data.  Windows uses Mathematica fonts.  Linux uses CairoFont.  That makes not sense to me.  But it's what's in the files.
